# How to close a sub form from another sub form without closing main form c#

Tags: c#, winforms

After open FORM 2.dialog from FORM 1, I want to close FORM 1 via button from FORM 2.

FORM 1

```
private void btnaddIPrange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new form2().ShowDialog();
}
```

FORM 2

```
private void btnIPRangeCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
    //close FORM 1(I don't know the code to close it)
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: I believe your problem is related to ShowDialog way. If you simply call Show and just after this command you set This.Close, you will open Form2 and close Form1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your forms are members of the same parent form, you can just call:

var ParentalForm = this.ParentForm as Foo_MainForm;

Make sure the child forms are public/internal members on the form.

Then:

ParentalForm.Foo_FormWantingClosed.Close();

Or in just one line:

(this.ParentForm as Foo_MainForm).Foo_FormWantingClosed.Close();

Off the top of my head.

Another idea! Since the form1 is sender, you can cast the object as form1 and close it directly. For instance:

```
private void OpenForm2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
    var callingForm = sender as form1;
    if (callingForm != null)
       {
           callingForm.Close();
       }
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: No worries, glad it helped!  I think it's a nicer way of going about things (cleaner) than some alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Form2 will need a reference to Form1. You can do that several ways.

For example, in Form1 you set the Owner property of the new Form2 instance to `this`:

```
private void btnaddIPrange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 myForm = new Form2(); // Creates instance of Form2.
    myForm.Owner = this; // Assigns reference to this instance of Form1 to the Owner property of Form2.
    myForm.Show(); // Opens Form2 instance.
    // You can also call myForm.Show(this);
    // instead of the above two lines to automatically assign this form as the owner.
}
```

Then in Form2:

```
private void btnIPRangeCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                        
    if(this.Owner != null) // Check for null.
        this.Owner.Close(); // Closes Form1 instance.
    this.Close(); // Closes current Form2 instance.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, well explained I immediately understand it even though I'm just a beginner. Thanks it worked.